# Alias command with parameters as arguments

Tags: terminal, command, alias, bash

I have created a alias function

```
move-jar(){
    mv ~/Downloads/$1 ~/Documents/$1
}
```

but when i do

```
move-jar sample.jar
```

it doesn't work and displays an error

> usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
>          mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

what is the issue in the command ? please help me out .

Comment: Does the actual filename have a space or other shell metacharacter in it?

Comment: it has  '-' as special char

Comment: That shouldn't cause any trouble, unless it's in a position where it could be mistaken for a command option (it isn't in this case). Try using `set -x` before calling the function; that'll print what the shell is actually executing, which might give a better idea what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full path for the file-names instead of tilde `~`

```
move-jar(){ mv "/home/user/Downloads/$1" "/home/user/Documents/$1"; }
```

And this one-liner works for me.

```
move-jar(){ mv ~/Downloads/$1 ~/Documents/$1; }
```